# GameObjects disappearing on run time while using set parent, how do I fix this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So I am currently making a bookworm like game and while attempting to set the lettertile as a child, the gameobjects somehow disappear on runtime.

basically what happens is that from this in the scene editor:
[scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY4Y1.png)
it goes to this:
[GameScene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBbH3.png)

when I checked the GameObjects to see if they were somehow destroyed, the GameObjects were still there so that wasn't the issue.

This was the code I worked with for the setparent logic:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class ParentSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool IsOnSlot = false;
    public GameObject[] LetterInputTile;
    public GameObject letterInputTileParent;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        letterInputTileParent = new GameObject("LetterInputTileParent");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(IsOnSlot)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < LetterInputTile.Length; i++)
            {
                LetterInputTile[i].transform.SetParent(letterInputTileParent.transform);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < LetterInputTile.Length; i++)
            {
                LetterInputTile[i].transform.SetParent(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("MLetterTile"))
        {
            IsOnSlot = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("MLetterTile"))
        {
            IsOnSlot = false;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Something about the sorting order? Also if these are UI if they are not nested under a Canvas you won't see them

Comment: Yup, I did see that for some reason, on run time they assign themselves, OUTSIDE the canvas which apparently caused the problem. This helped by the way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to post a screenshot where the problem is actualy seen, in your case we're missing the Hierarchy window where the objects layout can be observed.

I can only guess at this point, but it seems like you've doing something wrong, as maybe removing Canvas sub-objects away to non-Canvas parent.
UI components like Image, TMP_TextUGUI and anything that derives from Graphic class are depending on Canvas. If such an object is not under Canvas hierarchy, it won't be drawn even if its world position preserved.

Side note: you're doing state switch in Update without at least handling state check (to only do stuff once the state is changed). Even if called in Update(), such flip-flop logic will save you a ton of CPU power, but there is another way: using UnityEvents. UI components like Button, Toggle, TextInput are emiting events and you could subscribe to them, set your other object as a target, pick a method and it will respond. Here is a [good read](https://gamedevbeginner.com/events-and-delegates-in-unity/) on it.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that this is really what you want:

```
public bool IsOnSlot = false;
```

If there is no other logic that can set `IsOnSlot` to true, or if you set the boolean to `false` via the inspector, the if-else statement in `Update()` will always run the else statement. You can easily check if there is any other script that can access the boolean by using your IDE.

Next, in `Start()` you did this:

```
void Start()
{
    letterInputTileParent = new GameObject("LetterInputTileParent");
}
```

This is not the right way to spawn a new object in Unity. Usually you want to save a reference to the object you want to spawn via `[SerializeField]`, then use `Instantiate()` to spawn it. You can read more about `Instantiate()` in [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html).

Even if you did the right thing and use `Instantiate()`, the code above will still probably not run correctly because you are using `SetParent()` with a normal `GameObject` as a parameter. Remember, UI objects will only get rendered if they are children of a `Canvas` object, so make sure to assign a `Canvas` object to `letterInputTileParent`.

**So, to sum up:**

1. Make sure that 'IsOnSlot' is set to the right value.
2. Use `Instantiate()` instead of creating object via `new`.
3. Make sure that the parent object is a `Canvas`.